# Forms Authentication in Page_Load Event

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication

I have a form called frmLogin.  I have code within the Login_1Authenticate event handler that checks the security level of the username and password entered.  Then depending on the security level it will display or not display links on my main form called frmMain.  If it is security level “A” I want full control, but if it security level “U” then I want link buttons and image buttons removed from frmMain.  An example of two of them to disable are:

linkbtnEmployee
imgbtnNewEmployee

linkbtnViewUserActivity
imgbtnViewUserActivity

I need to write the code for the Page_Load event, but I’m not sure how to write it.
Here’s the code for my frmLogin page:

```
public partial class frmLogin : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
    {

        dsUser dsUserLogin;


        string SecurityLevel;


        dsUserLogin = clsDataLayer.VerifyUser(Server.MapPath("PayrollSystem_DB.mdb"),
                         Login1.UserName, Login1.Password);


        if (dsUserLogin.tblUserLogin.Count < 1)
        {
            e.Authenticated = false;
            return;
        }


        SecurityLevel = dsUserLogin.tblUserLogin[0].SecurityLevel.ToString();


        switch (SecurityLevel)
        {

            case "A":
                // Add your comments here
                e.Authenticated = true;
                Session["SecurityLevel"] = "A";
                break;
            case "U":
                // Add your comments here
                e.Authenticated = true;
                Session["SecurityLevel"] = "U";
                break;
            default:
                e.Authenticated = false;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if you want them to be invisible use:

```
linkbtnEmployee.Visible = false;
imgbtnNewEmployee.Visible = false;
```

Comment: Would I use an "if" statement?  If so how would it be set up?  Thanks

Comment: @Mike: Well you could use the same switch you used for the SecurityLevel. And on each case turn invisible the buttons that you want depending on the security level.

Comment: Thanks, but after doing it that way I get an error that says "The name 'linkbtnNewEmployee' does not exist in the current context".  I have the labels and images named correctly.  They are on frmMain though.  The code above is frmLogin.  Is that the problem?  Thanks

Comment: But in your question you said it's "linkbtnEmployee" not "linkbtnNewEmployee". Are you sure your names are correct?

Comment: Yes, I did have that one mispelled, but even after I changed it I still get the error.  I get it with all links and buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Please read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx

to understand "Forms Authentication in ASP.NET 2.0"